# Wrapping Text in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

Okay, I am kind of desperate right now. I hope you guys can help.

I need to layout content panels with Java Swing. The Problem is, that every content is different. So I need a panel that resize itself for every content. Basically what LayoutManagers are invented for.

I need a left panel and a right panel. The widths of the panels should be fixed. The heights should adjust to the given content

|<---- 30% ------->|<----- 70% -------------------->|

Easy going I thought, but it just wont work. I tried different layout managers. Some of them keep the 30% rule, but doesn't wrap the content and just display them in one single line (BorderLayout). 
If a LayoutManager does support line-break (even if its just for HTML text but that is fine for me) it wont support the fixed width. A combination of both didn't worked for me either.

Note that I need to stick to Swing and can not use another more advanced library because the system I am developing for is stuck to Java 1.5. Furthermore, I know the total screenwidth so I could calculate the width of the panels to work with fixed widths, but I need to be flexible with the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using nested `BorderLayouts`. Start by setting your Panel's layout as `BorderLayout`.

After that, for each left and right panels, set layouts as `BorderLayout` again. At this level, you will set %30 and %70 ratio.

Within this layouts, add your contents to `NORTH` layouts. This will enable your panels' height to match given content.

Comment: Thank you! With your hint I figured it out! 
For everybody who once have the same problem, remember that the BorderLayout resize the components due to their positions. 

Elements +WIDTH+ will be set by the LM in NORTH and SOUTH 
Elements +HEIGHT+ will be set by the LM in WEST and EAST

Eventhough you might think this is what you want, remember that "set" mean set to the given context, not to the given content(!). So if you want to resize to the given flexible heights, place them in NORTH or SOUTH, for flexibel width in WEST or EAST. Flexible includes the "preferredSize()" function.